# Android If registered launch service activity else launch registration activity

Tags: android, android-activity, service, launch

I was wondering how to make my app launch the service activity if the user is already registered?, it wont have login activity but registration activity. So the app will start with the registration activity, after registration it will go to the service activity. When user closes the app, how to make it launch again from the service activity and not from registration activity?

How to make it recognize if it is registered go to the service activity and if it is not launch the registration activity(login data will be stored in sharedpreferences I dont know any other way how to do it though in case it disconnects it will have to reconnect again)

I will appreciate any answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally for actions such as this I have an api where users login and if registered information then true is sent back, auto login if shared prefences found. If not then ask them to register.  Keeping it in shared preferences isn't bad though, it will save on shut downs and should be fine.

Comment: So I have to make my service a launcher right? then if doesnt find  sharedpreferences or login error, go to registration activity right?

Comment: I don't really see much wrong with that, if registration not found then launch.  I run something similar for a company I work for in login attempt is responded as not registered then make toast recommending registration, as this point you can launch it.

Comment: launch or go to activity?

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind that if the user clears the data or uninstalls the application, then the shared preferences will be lost and the user would have to re-register to use again as there is no Login Activity.

If this is something that does not bother you then [Ashley Alvarado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4777347/ashley-alvarado) is correct, and shared prefs is fine.

You can use [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) for storing values as well but it all depends on your app and how you want it.

I would think if you wanted something more serious then I think server side data would be the way to go, but would take some researching.

I'm currently doing something similar and I do use Shared Preferences in my app and SQLite as well. I'm trying to learn different ways to learn as I go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It will be SMS confirmation pin so it doesnt matter if the user clears data, me too, I am a beginner though.

Comment: Ah well shared prefs will be fine, hope it goes fine for.

Comment: I have a doubt about shared preference, if the person is a developer and opens the app with folder manager, can that person see the shared preference data? if so how can i make it private or at least encrypt it?

Comment: Yes they can see, in a folder manager it is stored in **/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml.** This can be accessed on a **ROOTED** device ... dangerous if data is stored this way and you lose your phone to someone that knows about this. Have a look into Crypto Library for security I believe.